# Netlogo - change shape color

Tags: netlogo, shapes

Can I change the color of the shape?
It the shape that I have generated as polygon
I tried

```
crt 1[
      set shape "myPoligon" ;works
      set heading 0         ;works
      set size 10           ;works
      set color red         ;doesn`t work
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the shapes manual: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/shapes.html#colors

Basically, when designing shapes you can use any color the shape editor provides. Below the color grid you will find a chooser named "Color that changes:". Here you define a color value, that adjusts according to the color variable of the turtle. All other colors of your shape will not change. By default the color "Gray" is selected. That means all "Gray" polygons and lines of your shape will not be displayed gray. Instead the color is defined by the color variable of the turtle. You can also verify this with the preview shapes at the bottom of the shape editor. They switch colors automatically and indicate areas of your shape that can be changed by setting the color variable of a turtle.